# java.io.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the path specified @PropertySource

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, annotations, filenotfoundexception

I can't figure out why my code can't find this file:

[image: File and folder structure]

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("file:config/my-app.properties")
```

I have tried with and without a "/" in front of config, but same error. I pulled this straight from my company repo, so it seems to work for everyone else, but not working for me...

Any ideas?

ETA:

After I posted this question

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/my-app.properties")
```

made it work, but I just did a pull and corrected it to this and now nothing is working

after hours of searching, I found many different offerings. I have tried:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/my-app.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:config/my-app.properties")
@PropertySource("/my-app.properties")
```

Any ideas on what else I can try?